# Ordering panel data in ggplot2 by the value of the observation in one certain year

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am plotting a simple panel of data with ggplot2. Observations from the same individual (region) are from two different waves, and I want to plot my graph ordering individuals by the value of only one of the waves. However, ggplot by default orders by the mean value of both waves. Here's a basic sample of the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6WIOTEfKlv3T0pwSHRpOXBBUlU/view?usp=sharing).

```
data <- read.table(text = "

 ID  Country time     Theil0
 1      AT1 2004 0.10358155
 2      AT2 2004 0.08181044
 3      AT3 2004 0.08238252
 4      BE1 2004 0.14754138
 5      BE2 2004 0.07205898
 6      BE3 2004 0.09522730
 7      AT1 2010 0.10901556
 8      AT2 2010 0.09593889
 9      AT3 2010 0.07579683
 10     BE1 2010 0.16500438
 11     BE2 2010 0.08313131
 12     BE3 2010 0.10281853

", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

And here's the code for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

pd <- position_dodge(0.4)

ggplot(data, aes(x=reorder(Country, Theil0), y=Theil0, colour = as.factor(time))) +   
   geom_point(size=3, position = pd)+
   xlab("Region") +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
   ylab("Index") +
   ggtitle("2004 and 2010")
```

And the resulting plot:
[image]

As you can see, ordering by the values of 2010 only (and not the average of both years) would make the BE2 and AT3 observations switch order, which is what I would prefer in the graph. Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a reproducible example that uses generic `x`s and `y`s. Basically, you need to use the `ordered` function on your factor:

```
x <- letters[1:4]
y1 <- 1:4
y2 <- c(1, 4, 2, 5) + 1

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) # used to melt the dummy dataset

df <- data.frame(x = x, y1 = y1, y2 = y2)
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = "x", variable.name = "Group", value.name = "y")

df2$Group <- factor(df2$Group)
gg1 <- ggplot(data = df2, aes( x = x, y = y, color = Group)) +
       geom_point()
ggsave("eample1.jpg", gg1, width = 3, height = 3)
```

Gives a plot similar to what you had:
[image]

However, `x` may be reorder:

```
df2$x2 <- ordered(df2$x, x[order(y2)])
gg2 <- ggplot(data = df2, aes( x = x2, y = y, color = Group)) +
       geom_point()
ggsave("eample2.jpg", gg2, width = 3, height = 3)
```

which gives this figure:

[image]

Also, I get tripped up on this a lot. I find adjusting levels in `ggplot2` to be trick at times.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I think this could solve it, assuming the y2 variable is still in the work environment and could be called, right?. I found a similar workaround: when making the data long with the reshape function (or melting with reshape2), I kept my 'y2' variable (the Theil0 index for the year 2010) time invariant. This way I have it for each individual for both factor levels and can be use to order as desired.

Comment: In fact what I do is duplicate my y2 variable in wide format, and passing to long format only one of the duplicates. The other variable duplicate is time invariant (I do not include it in the 'varying' list in the reshape function) and it serves to order the data later. However, other solutions that do not require previous formatting (or calling old variables in wide form such as y2) could be helpful and more straight forward.